# Population size and genetic drift - What are the evidences?

Tags: genetics, evolution, population-genetics, population-dynamics

**Wright-Fisher model**

From the Wright-Fisher model of genetic drift, the random sampling of allele from one generation to the next is taken from a binomial distribution with parameters $2N$ and $p$, where $N$ is the population size and $p$ the frequency of an allele of interest.

**Strength of Genetic drift**

The strength of genetic drift can be measured in terms of two different statistics:

- variance in allele frequency from one generation to the next
- loss of heterozygosity per generation

**Variance in allele frequency from one generation to the next**

From the above, it is relatelively straight forward to show that the variance in allele frequency in the successive generation is

$$\text{var}\left(p'\right) = \frac{p(1-p)}{2N}$$

, where $N$ is the population size.

**Loss of heterozygosity**

Heterozygosity decays by $1-\frac{1}{2N}$ every generation

$$H_t = H_{t-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{2N}\right)$$

, where $H_t$, is the expected heterozygosity at time $t$.

**Source**

See [Gillespie: Population Genetics - A concise guide](https://www.amazon.ca/Population-Genetics-Gillespie-Publisher-Fulfillment/dp/B00SQBY84O/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1461085333&sr=8-2&keywords=gillespie%20population%20genetics) chapter 2 for more info on these predictions.

**Question**

Do we have empirical evidence that the decay rate in heterozygosity and/or the variance in allele frequency due to genetic drift follows these predictions?

Comment: I suppose it's quite complex, would need large amounts of replication and have to neutralise/standardise selection and mutation across replicates - maybe mutation accumulation experiments would be worth investigating

Comment: This paper looks interesting https://www.researchgate.net/publication/11126342_Microsatellite_DNA_evidence_for_genetic_drift_and_philopatry_in_Svalbard_reindeer but it's not quite what you are looking for I think

Comment: In natural populations? No. This is why people generally talk about "effective population size". (I'm not a fan of this term though -- if we mean "the diffusion parameter of allele frequencies" or "the rate of decay of heterozygosity", we should just say so!)

Comment: Not necessarily in natural population. I was rather thinking about experimental evolution. Someone may have produced an experimental evolution where the population is as close as possible to a wright-fisher population (random mating, constant population, no selection, non-overlapping generation; so that $N=Ne$) and test whether the model offers good predictions.